# MongoDB update queries slow after PHP driver update

Tags: php, mongodb

Since updating our mongo PHP drivers from 1.4.1 to 1.6.6 update and insert queries have become approximately 5x slower.

There's been no change to the MongoDB server, we are on 2.6.4

Has anyone else experienced this, is this a known issue with later drivers in PHP?

We're running RHEL 6.4, PHP 5.4

according to http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/php/ we should be 100% compatible and supported

Comment: This is probably better off on the JIRA where the maintainers can look at it